# If $c_1,\dots, c_h$ are the orders of the centralisers of elements of distinct conjugacy classes of a finite group, then $1/c_1+\dots+1/c_h=1$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

This is part of **Exercise 1.6.8** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*.

### The Details:

The *centraliser* of an element $x$ in a group $G$ is defined as

$$C_G(x)=\{g\in G\mid xg=gx\}.$$

The *conjugacy class* of $x$ is defined as

$$Cl(x)=\{gxg^{-1}\mid g\in G\}.$$

---

The previous part of the exercise in question is as follows.

> **Lemma:** Let $G$ be a finite group. The elements of the same conjugacy class have conjugate centralisers.

*Proof:* Let $x,y\in Cl(a)$ for some $a\in G$. Then there exist $g,h\in G$ such that $x=gag^{-1}$ and $y=hah^{-1}$. Note that $gh=f$ for $f\in G$, solved for $g$, has the unique solution $g=fh^{-1}$. We have

$$\begin{align}
C_G(x)&=\{k\in G\mid kx=xk\}\\
&=\{k\in G\mid kgag^{-1}=gag^{-1}k\}\\
&=\{k\in G\mid (kg)a(kg)^{-1}=gag^{-1}\}\\
&=\{k\in G\mid (kfh^{-1})a(kfh^{-1})^{-1}=(fh^{-1})a(fh^{-1})^{-1}\}\\
&=\{k\in G\mid (f^{-1}kf)h^{-1}ah(f^{-1}kf)^{-1}=h^{-1}ah\}\\
&=\{b=f^{-1}kf\in G\mid byb^{-1}=y\}\\
&=f\{k\in G\mid (fkf^{-1})y=y(fkf^{-1})\}f^{-1}\\
&=f\{K\in G\mid Ky=yK\}f^{-1}\\
&=fC_G(y)f^{-1},
\end{align}$$

because $fkf^{-1}$ runs through $G$ just as an arbitrary $K\in G$ does.$\square$

*(I'm sorry about the garbled proof. I'm trying to piece together my understanding without recourse to external sources.)*

### The Question

> If $c_1,\dots, c_h$ are the orders of the centralisers of elements of distinct conjugacy classes of a finite group, then $1/c_1+\dots+1/c_h=1$.

### Thoughts:

This might require a combinatorial approach (in the numerical sense), since it involves counting, but of reciprocals; that's where I'm struggling: I can't use anything beyond the number of conjugacy classes being

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in G}|{\rm Fix}(\pi)|,$$

by **Exercise 1.6.2**, where ${\rm Fix}(\pi)$ is the number of fixed points of the action of conjugacy on $\pi$. (I'm a little unsure of this. Have I got it right?)

I know that conjugation partitions the underlying set of $G$. This is mentioned earlier in the book.

Please help :)

Comment: Along with an induction argument for Egyptian fractions, this is used to show that for each $n$ there are finitely many finite groups (up to isomorphism) with $n$ conjugacy classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :** The class equation is
$$|G|=\sum_{g \in G}|Cl(g)|=\sum_{g \in G}|G:C_G(g)|=\sum_{g \in G}{|G|\over |C_G(g)|}$$
where we're taking only one $g$ from each conjugacy class.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This works because the class equation is on page 38 of the edition of Robinson's book, whereas the exercise in question is on page 43.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the action of conjugacy, the stabilizer of an element is exactly its centralizer. Let $\gamma_i$ be the cardinality of the conjugacy class of the i-th conjugacy class. Since the product of the orbit of an element and its stabilizer is $|G|$, we have that $\gamma_i c_i = |G| $. Hence

$$ \sum_{i=1}^h 1/c_i = \sum_{i=1}^h \gamma_i / |G| = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{i=1}^h \gamma_i  = 1$$

Since the sum of the cardinalities of all the conjugacy classes sum up to $|G|$ (the conjugacy classes are a partition of $G$).